# How do I reference text contained within a textbox to create an XML file?

Tags: .net, c++, forms, visual-c++, save

I am using visual c++ 2005 .net and I am looking to create a file from this form. I want to be able to name the file by entering what ever is in the text box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the form:

[image]

this is what I have so far:

```
  private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        String^ path = "C:\\" ".txt" ;

        StreamWriter^ sw = File::CreateText( path );

        try
          {
             sw->WriteLine("");

          }
          finally
          {
             if ( sw )
                      delete (IDisposable^)sw;
          }

                 }
        };
```

FIXED CODE:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {               

     NewPart ^newpart = gcnew NewPart();
                     newpart->ShowDialog();
                     this->Close();

                    String^ fileName = textBox1->Text;
                    String^ filetype = ".xml";
                    String^ path = L"C:\\;

                     String^ fullName = path + fileName + filetype;

                    StreamWriter^ sw = File::CreateText(fullName);

        try
          {
             sw->WriteLine("<?xml version= \"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
             sw->WriteLine("<macdata");
             sw->WriteLine("</macdata>");

          }
          finally
          {
             if ( sw )
                      delete (IDisposable^)sw;
          }

                 }


        };
    }
```

Comment: Is your problem getting the text from the form, or creating the file?

Comment: Okay I have figured out how to create the file but I cannot figure out how to get teh text from the box.

Comment: Reference the text contained within the textbox.  Why are you using such an old version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String^ path = textBox1->Text;
```

Replace textBox1 with actual TextBox name from your form.

Edit. Regarding your second question, look at this code:

```
int main(array ^args)
{
    String^ fileName = L"file.txt";
    String^ path = L"C:\\";

    String^ fullName = path + fileName;

    Console::WriteLine(fullName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is great thank you very much however how would I go about concatanating it so before it reads whats in the textbox it finds the directory such as "C:\\"